# Facebook app throws 405 error while subscribing the webhook

Tags: facebook, http-status-code-405

Facebook app successfully subscribes to the webhook in test environment. But throws 405 error while subscribing the webhook in the production environment. Could some one help me on this?

Sample production webhook url: https://webhook.klamp.io/webhook/ejBwXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

APP Id: 1478431015994369

I did not change any settings after moving to the production environment. Why could be the reason for getting the 405 error?

Comment: You usually get a 405 Method Not Allowed, when a POST request is made to what the server considers to be a "static" resource, but there can be other reasons as well. Can't tell you more, based on the info we have here so far.